# How to correctly interpret results of logistics regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, contrasts

I ran a logistics regression on my data where I am trying to predict the affect state using the emotions. I am trying to predict SelfReport State (factors are "FLOW" and "NOFLOW") using the values of Anger, Disgust, Fear, Happiness, Sadness, Surprise, Contempt, Valence which are all continuous and belongs to the range [0,100], except valence which is in the range [-100,100].

Data looks like the one below:
[image]

Below is the piece of code that I am executing using the tutorial from this [page](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-perform-a-logistic-regression-in-r/).

```
library(ROCR)
library(Amelia)
library(readxl)
library(psych)
library(irr)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(pscl)
library(readr)
library(openxlsx)

# LOGISTIC REGRESSION FOR FLOW
flowData$SelfReport <- as.factor(flowData$SelfReport)

# Split Data into Training and Testing in R 
sample_size = floor(0.8*nrow(flowData))
set.seed(777)
# randomly split data in r
picked = sample(seq_len(nrow(flowData)),size = sample_size)
train = flowData[picked,]
test = flowData[-picked,]

emoteModel <- glm(SelfReport~.,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=train)

summary(emoteModel)
# gives following equation
# ln(p/(1-p)) = 0.833437 - 0.006937Anger - 0.058744Disgust - 0.450645Fear - 0.082815Happiness + 0.072097Sadness + 0.036079Surprise - 0.006641Contempt - 0.013099Valence
# what is p here, probability of "FLOW" or "NOFLOW"?
fitted.results <- predict(emoteModel,newdata=subset(test,select=c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)),type='response')
fitted.results <- ifelse(fitted.results > 0.5,"FLOW","NOFLOW") # or should it be other way around, i.e. ifelse(fitted.results > 0.5,"NOFLOW","FLOW")
misClasificError <- mean(fitted.results != test$SelfReport)
print(paste('Accuracy',1-misClasificError))
```

However, I am not sure if p here refers to the probability of state being FLOW or NOFLOW. I request you to help me interpret it correctly.

UPDATE: It seems like `contrasts(flowData$SelfReport)` is the one which is helpful here. As per the coding shown below, p is probability of it being NOFLOW.

[image]

UPDATE: found a bit of info [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/logistic-regression-R#comments), but that info is based on his code test. so I can not be sure about how good is it.

[image]

UPDATE: It seems like `contrasts(flowData$SelfReport)` is the one which is helpful here. As per the coding shown below, p is probability of it being NOFLOW.

[image]

Comment: I just recoded the factor levels to make sure I do not interpret the result incorrectly. `flowData$SelfReport <- revalue(flowData$SelfReport, c("FLOW"="1", "NOFLOW"="0"))`

Comment: It seems that even though I am encoding FLOW AS 1, it is being codes as 0 by R. > `contrasts(flowData$SelfReport)
  0
1 0
0 1`

Comment: Posting it on stackoverflow, seems like a better place to ask than here..

Comment: Just make `SelfReport` a binary (0/1) variable and you can choose which value is 1 and which is 0. p is the probability of 1.

Comment: @Noah I tried that, but it seems like it was encoding 0 to 1. i did as indicated above using `flowData$SelfReport <- revalue(flowData$SelfReport, c("FLOW"="1", "NOFLOW"="0"))`

Comment: is there a way to identify what is FLOW encoded as? from the output of `contrasts(flowData$SelfReport)` it seems like it is being encoded as 0, but not sure. I don't want to risk interpreting the results other way round :/

Comment: @Noah is there  way to check that the interpretation is correct? I tried using prediction both on the training and test data and still could not reach a conclusion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly interpret results of logistics regression in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/454730/how-to-correctly-interpret-results-of-logistics-regression-in-r)

Comment: do you even see an answer there @kjetilbhalvorsen. lol

Comment: It looks like you solved this, but your `revalue` statement is incorrect. I meant to code `SelfReport` as a **numeric** 0/1 variable (i.e., `flowData$SelfReport_num <- as.numeric(flowData$SelfReport == "FLOW")`). You coded it as a string/factor, which is the source of the problem in the first place. But yes, you can also go by the order of the factor levels. You can change the order using the `relevel()` function if you want to switch which is the focal event when using a factor.

Comment: yes, that worked. Thank you @Noah

Comment: can you add it as an answer please?